# How to make Background black and Foreground White in OpenCV?

Tags: android, opencv

I am doing Some image processing on image using OpenCV, i want to get an image that will always have black background and white foreground(text) on it,the problem is that i can invert the the image having white bg and black fg using BINARY_INV, but when user gives black bg and white fg how can i identify that image has already black bg not white so i wont have to invert it.i hope i made myself clear.
here is a sample.
[Sample Image](http://s30.postimg.org/ugbxrvjrl/Untitled.png)

[New Image](http://s28.postimg.org/b0mieb62l/test9.jpg)

Comment: Use majority count? Or if that doesn't work, check out values along the border (should work for your example).

Comment: 1-If u mean counting pixel values, than that could be a problem when user gives input a cropped image,with bold text covering more area than background,in this case majority of pixels which will be of foreground will be considered as background.

Comment: 2-and for the border values,as this image is actually an image captured from camera,sometimes this text is enclosed in border.and this border will interfere in calculating actual border.

Comment: How about using contours to find the bounding boxes for the letters as we discussed earlier. Then dilate the image - white bits get whiter. Repeat the first step - if it's white text, the bounding boxes will get bigger; if it's black they will get smaller. Deduce the background from the text colour.

Comment: when i try to find contours on image that is black bg,and after invert threshold, it becomes white bg.(inverting becoz most of time input image will have white bg) due to this i cant find contours properly.e.g the whole image is selected as one contour.so to find contours i must have an image that has black bg not white.
see the new image i added.

Comment: If you find all the contours not just the outer ones (use CV_RETR_LIST) and then exclude those that have the size close to the size of the image that should eliminate the border round the entire background.

Comment: I just tried what u suggested,u might remember my last question,it was solved by using hierarchy information,the logic was if the contour is inner contour of another contour it wont be drawn,now i can detect the border contour but the inner contours wont be drawn becoz of it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem myself.if Findcontours are applied on white bg,it always detects the border of image as a contour,so i implemented a logic that if the biggest contour has size equal to the size of the image,then invert the image.its not a best solution but works wonderfully for my specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

to draw the inner contours you can find contours with hierarchy, and then draw only the child contours, meaning the one containing the digits and alphabets, and not draw the outside parent contour